# Warning about redeclaration of friend function

Tags: c++

I've got A.h where I have

```
#ifndef _FOO_
#define _FOO_
namespace FOO {
    const std::string& getName();
}
#endif
```

In B.h I have

```
#ifndef _BAR_
#define _BAR_
namespace FOO {
    //forward declaration
    const std::string& getName();
}

namespace BAR {
class Baz {
private:
   static std::string& get();
public:
   friend const std::string& FOO::getName();
}
}
#endif
```

In B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
namespace BAR {
       std::string& Baz::get() {
            static std::string s;
            return s;
       }
}
```

In A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
namespace FOO {
const std::string& getName() {
    return BAR::Baz::get();
}
}
```

When I compile I have the following warning from GCC:

> redundant redeclaration of 'const string& FOO::getName()' in the same
> scope. [-Wredundant-decls]

The warning is for A.h during compilation of A.cpp. How come?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Do you have include guards?

Comment: yes, of course. Include guards are present. It's a larger code but I inserted only the needed one.

Comment: "A.cpp" must include "B.h", either directly or indirectly, or `BAR::Baz::get()` wouldn't compile.

Comment: How can you compile A.cpp without including B.h? There is no `BAR::Baz` in A.h. Please provide a [mcve] (with includes) because currently your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated the question

Comment: Wait a sec. You declare `getName()` in both headers? Rather than have one include the other?

Comment: Yes, because I wanted to forward declare the function.

Comment: `#ifdef _FOO_` should be `#ifndef _FOO_` and so on. Also identifiers starting from _ followed by capital letter are reserved.

Comment: @user7860670 Updated

Comment: Both headers have the declaration. Neither is preprocessed out because the guards are wrong. (You should be able to find, in your compiler's documentation, a switch to check what the preprocessor outputs.)

Comment: Can't reproduce. I can compile without error. I get a linker error: https://wandbox.org/permlink/KPjdFuuUgJN79zrn Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: In `B.h` you should include `A.h` instead of redeclaring `getName`

Comment: @user7860670 So can't I forward declare it to decouple the header files?

Comment: I still can't reproduce: https://wandbox.org/permlink/dmYqtpgiHMZk2Tiq It works with forward declaration.

Comment: `redundant redeclaration of 'const string& FOO::getName()' in the same scope.` could be a missing include guard somewhere in your code or a declaration additionally to an include. But the forward declaration in your posted code works and is correct.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, I just said it's a warning of GCC 4.8 using the option -Wredundant-decls

Comment: Duplication of header content is one of the most severe forms of coupling of the headers.

Answer (score 0):

> The warning is for A.h during compilation of A.cpp. How come?

The warning message explains the reason for its existence. You've unnecessarily declared `FOO::getName` twice. The second declaration is called a redeclaration.

Solution: Instead of manually redeclaring the content of the other header, `#include`  A.h into B.h. The include guard will prevent the redundant redeclaration.

---

P.S. The header guard macros that you use are reserved to the language implementation. As a consequence, the behaviour of the program will be undefined.